# How to submit mahout recommendation Jobs using HDInsight .NET SDK

Tags: hadoop, mahout, azure-hdinsight

I'm new to HDInsight. I want to learn and practice machine learning, HDInsight is just what i want, but there seems no direct API to mahout. Since mahout recommendation will translate to mapredure job essentially, so I followed some mapreduce example on Windows Azure documentation and write the following code：

```
// Define the MapReduce job
MapReduceJobCreateParameters mrJobDefinition = new MapReduceJobCreateParameters()
{
    JarFile = "wasb:///example/jars/mahout-core-0.9-job.jar",
    ClassName = "org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob",
};

mrJobDefinition.Arguments.Add(" -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE");
mrJobDefinition.Arguments.Add(" --input=/reply");
mrJobDefinition.Arguments.Add(" --output=/recommend/");
mrJobDefinition.Arguments.Add(" --usersFile=/data/users.txt");
```

I have already upload the "mahout-core-0.9-job.jar" to /example/jars in the specified Azure blob storage container.

But I received the following error message:

> 14/04/03 12:04:28 ERROR **security.UserGroupInformation**: **PriviledgedActionException** as:johnny cause:**java.io.IOException**: Exception reading **file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken=**
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken=
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1233)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:951)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:77)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:164)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:322)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken=
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:136)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.readTokensFromFiles(JobClient.java:2149)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.populateTokenCache(JobClient.java:2185)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$300(JobClient.java:179)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:964)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:951)
>       ... 16 more
>   Caused by: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken= does not exist**.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:427)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:254)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:436)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:130)
>       ... 21 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken=
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:136)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.readTokensFromFiles(JobClient.java:2149)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.populateTokenCache(JobClient.java:2185)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$300(JobClient.java:179)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:964)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:951)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1233)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:951)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:77)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:164)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
>       at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:322)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
>   Caused by: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/c:/apps/temp/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/johnny/jobcache/job_201404031203_0001/jobToken= does not exist**.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:427)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:254)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:436)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:130)
>       ... 21 more
>   Shutting down watcher/keep alive thread pool forcefully
>   templeton: job failed with exit code 1

After I Googled on the internet, it seems some change should be made to mapred-site.xml or other hadoop config files.But I'm totally new to Apache hadoop and doesn't have much knowledge about Linux and Java.

Any help or direction would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest .NET SDK for Hadoop (http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/), I can submit the mahout job with the same code successfully. It seems this issue has been resolved by the SDK.